# Forge AWS stuck on provisioning "ERROR: role "forge" already exists"

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-forge

I'm trying to create a server on forge and AWS following [this](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-forge-hosting-on-aws) tutorial

On my first attempt, I got stuck on provisioning for over 20 minutes so I decided to delete it and try again.

Now when I execute the code from Forge when SSH'd into aws, I get an error

"ERROR:  role "forge" already exists" however I don't actually specify a role of "forge" anywhere that I know of

I am also asked to overwrite my ssh key, I have tried both yes and no, and I still get stuck on the same server provisioning.

Anyone know what to do? Would really like to push my code into production :-)

edit: this is  a work in progress, will update back as necessary

```
current workflow
 - delete previous 'provisioning' server on forge
 - ssh into aws
 - aws listed as 'ubuntu@previousforgeservername' - something is happening anyway
 - tried to continue with process, get same error 'role forge already exists'
 - new attempt, $ ps aux | grep forge // lists instances running as 'forge'
 - delete them (3 running ) with pkill -9 'id'
 - sudo rm forge.sh // download again
 - run the code wget -0 .... to download forge.sh and provision server
 - same bs.. 

useradd: user 'forge' already exists
The user `forge' is already a member of `sudo'.
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
/home/forge/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)?
```

Not sure what to do here. Tried both y/n

Results in the same error

ERROR:  role "forge" already exists

How can I delete the role?

```
ubuntu@polished-badlands:~$ ps aux | grep forge
forge     7797  0.0  0.9 473836  9448 ?        S    17:21   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
forge     7801  0.0  0.3 148640  3432 ?        S    17:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
forge     7804  0.0  0.9 473836  9448 ?        S    17:21   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
ubuntu    7806  0.0  0.0  12952   928 pts/0    S+   17:21   0:00 grep --color=auto forge
ubuntu@polished-badlands:~$ sudo userdel -r forge
userdel: user forge is currently used by process 7797
ubuntu@polished-badlands:~$ sudo kill 7797
ubuntu@polished-badlands:~$ sudo userdel -r forge
userdel: user forge is currently used by process 7801
ubuntu@polished-badlands:~$ sudo kill 7801
ubuntu@polished-badlands:~$ sudo userdel -r forge
userdel: user forge is currently used by process 7804
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake

During the build I specified my own ip for ssh which forge had a problem with. Need to follow the instructions in the guide.

Hope this helps someone!